# Каким членом предложения является слово "сильнее"?

Tags: сказуемые, члены-предложения, основа

Нашла в Сети интересный вопрос. Надо определить грамматическую основу предложения (экзамен в 8 классе): ***Всё это делало его сильнее.***

Ответ ученика: Все делало (про слово «это» не знает).

Ответы на форуме: Это делало сильнее.  Все это делало сильнее.

Меня заинтересовало сказуемое. Никто не усомнился в том, что это составное именное сказуемое.

Для сравнения: Все это делало его сильным.

А вы как думаете?

Answer (score 3):

Прилагательное **"сильнее"** - именная часть составного сказуемого **"делало сильнее"** (в случае "душило его сильнее" сказуемое было бы простым глагольным). Видимо, трудность принять это состоит в том, что в учебные примеры, сопровождающие определение составного именного сказуемого, крайне редко включают такие, когда между частями сказуемого оказывается *дополнение*.

Вот редкий пример с дополнением внутри составного именного сказуемого https://rg.ru/2011/01/21/skazuemoe-site.html :

> Он показался **мне** стариком. (из "Русского синтаксиса в научном
> освещении" А. М. Пешковского.)

Пример (по той же ссылке) с разделённым на части составным глагольным сказуемым:

> Через несколько дней должен **я** был очутиться посреди моего
> семейства. (А. Пушкин)

В нашем же случае тип сказуемого не изменится, если переставить местоимение "его":

> **Его** всё это делало сильнее [укрепляло].

Comment: *в случае "душило его сильнее" сказуемое было бы простым глагольным* — да, потому что здесь изъятие возможно.

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо за ответ, завтра внимательно посмотрю.

Answer (score 1):

По идее, должно входить в сказуемое, потому что при его изъятии предложение становится некорректным.

Таким же методом мы проверяем, входит ли оборот в сказуемое. Если входит — то он не обособляется:
*Он всё сделал как положено.*

Comment: Он стал сильным. Это СИС, стал — связка, согласуется с подлежащим "он". Это сделало его сильным.  Это — подлежащее, а сильным стал он (дополнение).  Странно как-то. Может, это и сказуемое, но глагол "делать" на связку в именном сказуемом не очень похож.

Comment: Да не странно. Не он же сам себя сделал сильным. Поэтому не он и подлежащее. В общем, так: вижу разницу при изъятии — *он стал (всё-таки)* (более-менее приемлемо) vs *это делало его* (бред). Так может, случаи разные?

Comment: СИС – составное именное сказуемое.   Грамматическое подлежащее  – ЭТО (с частицей ВСЁ),  а  он – субъект состояния, так как ЕГО – грамматическое  дополнение. Здесь у нас двунаправленная связь: определение "сильный" согласуется с дополнением в роде и числе, а глагол задает ему падеж.

Comment: В "делало таким-то" просматривается цельность. Поэтому оно целиком должно быть сказуемым.

Comment: Ничего оно вам не должно :)  А мне нужен точный ответ – в чем тут дело?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А этот пример для вас:  И для тебя горит звезда одна (одинокая). Это дуплексив «одна»: согласуется с подлежащим, но управляется глаголом. Сравнить:  Пете страшно одному (глагол задает Д.п. дополнению и предикативному определению). Можно сказать: горит одинокая, горит одиноко. Так как предикативное определение управляется глаголом, то обстоятельственное значение присутствует. Собственно говоря,  обстоятельство образа действия всегда имеет признаковое значение (ведь нет большой разницы между «какая» и «как»).

Comment: Ну тогда в моём примере тем более присутствует: *Звезда горит в небе одна.*

Comment: В примере - да, присутствует, вот только структура у предложения  некорректная.

Comment: Почему некорректная? Нестандартная — да. Ещё примеры (такая же структура): *Она танцует в зале одна. Она гуляет в парке одна.*

Comment: От контекста зависит, можно подобрать соответствующий, чтобы ударение падало "на одна" : С кем она гуляет - Она гуляет одна. Для звезды такой текст не подберешь, а в заданном  тексте нет такого значения. Там вообще инверсия сочетания "одна звезда - звезда одна".

Answer (score 1):

Alex_ander, я думаю, что здесь не тот случай, который вы рассматриваете в примерах.  «*Он показался мне стариком*». Здесь все нормально: он – подлежащее, показался стариком – сказуемое. Предикативный признак относится **к подлежащему**.

1. Дело не в особой позиции дополнения – его всегда можно переставить, это актуальное членение предложения.  Дело  в том, что это **особенное** дополнение,  так как к нему относится именная часть (сильным, сильнее) и согласуется с ним, а не подлежащим «это».
2. Такое определение называется ДУПЛЕКСИВОМ – членом предложения с двунаправленной связью. Падеж дуплексиву  задает глагол (сделало сильным), а в роде и числе он согласуется с существительным (а в нашем предложении – с ДОПОЛНЕНИЕМ).

Предложения такого вида не редкость, но обычно существительное, с которым согласуется дуплексив,  является ПОДЛЕЖАЩИМ: он стал сильным/сильнее.  Мы считаем, что это СИС и не обращаем особого внимания на такие предложения. Но когда дуплексив относится к дополнению, то такой разбор кажется странным – ведь признак не относится к подлежащему.

3. В учебнике Кустовой рассматривается эта проблем. Там предлагается такой вариант разбора: **сказуемое двойного типа** как сочетание простого глагольного сказуемого с предикативным определением.  В случае с дополнением такой подход весьма актуален.

Но все-таки такие предложения – это не тема для 8 класса. Что касается других пользователей русского языка с указанного форума, то они даже не замечают такие вещи, что весьма огорчительно.

**Примеры предложений** (предикативное определение относится к дополнению):  *Однажды я застал его плачущим. Пусть запомнит меня молодой.  Пете страшно одному*. Эти предложения представляют трудность для школьного разбора.

**Для справок** (Кустова Г.И., стр. 72)
[https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

В связочной функции глагол меняет значение по сравнению с автономным употреблением, сравним: На дороге показался всадник (ПГС) — Он показался мне усталым (СИС); У тебя все получится — Линия получилась неровной.

Вопрос о статусе знаменательной связки и квалификации сказуемого типа *пришел усталый, расстались друзьями* и подобных решается по-разному. Поскольку знаменательная связка не является служебным компонентом в точном смысле слова, а выражает наряду с именем **полноценный предикативный признак**, то сказуемые данного типа иногда рассматриваются как «двойные», как сложные, как сочетание простого глагольного сказуемого с предикативным определением (дуплексивом).

Comment: Разница между примерами - преимущественно в характере составного сказуемого, которое в нашем случае эквивалентно выраженному _переходным_ глаголом (укрепляло; отсюда прямое дополнение), а в примере с "показалось ему" - _непереходным_ (дополнение в дательном падеже). Грамматическая согласованность эквивалентного глагола с подлежащим (здесь по роду и числу) не зависит от наличия прямого дополнения (его можно опустить: Всё это делает сильнее, ставит в тупик и т. п.). Да, примеры, иллюстрирующие определение СИС, обычно не включают в себя наш случай ("эквивалентного переходного глагола"),

Comment: но и воспользоваться комментарием из Кустовой ([в случае _знаменательной_ связки] _иногда_ рассматриваются  как «двойные»,  как сложные, как сочетание  простого  глагольного  сказуемого  с предикативным определением /дуплексивом/) нет оснований, поскольку в нашем случае связка _полузнаменательная._ Думаю, что тип сказуемого не изменится и при перестройке с заменой глагола-связки на возвратный (непереходный): _От всего этого он сделался сильнее_.

Comment: Alex_ander,  я не все поняла в вашем ответе, и вот о чем подумала.  Обычно мы общаемся так:  один участник приводит цепочку своих рассуждений, другой – свою цепочку, они не соглашаются, а  причина разногласий часто остается неясной. Поэтому я предлагаю вам НОВЫЙ  ФОРМАТ  ОБЩЕНИЯ –  пошаговый. Например,  шаг 1.  Я привожу очень короткое утверждение, а вы отвечаете – да или нет. Если да, я привожу следующее утверждение, если нет – то на этом дискуссия останавливается ввиду принципиального разногласия. Попробуем?

Comment: Шаг 1. В двусоставном предложении  именная часть сказуемого называет предикативный признак подлежащего: Он стал сильным. В предложении «Это сделало его сильным/сильнее»  именная часть называет признак дополнения, а не подлежащего, поэтому это не СИС (составное именное сказуемое). Да?

Comment: Нет, поскольку из определений СИС не следует такая функция отдельно именной части.

Comment: Обсуждаем шаг 1.  Я перехожу к общему определению сказуемого любого вида (в двух источниках).   (1) Грамота.ру  Сказуемое — главный член двусоставного предложения, обозначающий действие или признак того, что выражено ПОДЛЕЖАЩИМ. http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part5#312  (2) Студопедия. Сказуемое  обозначает предикативный признак, т.е. признак предмета, названного ПОДЛЕЖАЩИМ, в модально-временном плане. Признак понимается здесь широко – это действие, свойство, состояние...
https://studopedia.ru/3_79386_skazuemoe-tipi-skazuemih-i-sposobi-virazheniya.html